# Javascript modal that displays list that closes and returns to main html

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

Rather new to javascript, jquery and bootstrap, etc., so bear with me. I have a situation where I want to present a list of errors in a model dialog after the user hits a "validate" button. Got all the working - I am generating a list of objects that indicate to the user they need more work to the exact spot that needs additional data entry. I have the the DIV "id" that represents the field that needs more data (and each item will jump someplace different).I do not want a drop down list since there are be lots and lots of these items.

A few questions:

1. How do I go about jumping from the modal to the main html. I believe I have seen scrollIntoView mentioned in a few other posts as I was looking but will that hop to the DIV and also close the modal?
2. What construct should I use for the list? A list of scrolling button? The size of this can be quite large (hundreds) so it will need a scroll capability.
3. Finally, the app is "paged" with a next and prev buttons. I assume that will not be a problem from the aspect of jumping to a page not already displayed?

Here is the current modal code:

```
<script id="template-validation-error" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div id="validationErrorModal" class="modal">
        <div class="message-container">
            <div class="header">
                Validation Errors
            </div>
            <div class="message">
                The following fields are required:
            </div>
            <div class="center">
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-solid-green btn-sm" onclick="fffdevice.validationErrorOk();" value="Done" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

and

```
showValidationError: function (fieldlist) {
    settings.focusedField = $(':focus');
    $("#validationErrorModal").detach();
    $(".device-container").append(templates.validationerror({ fieldlist }));
    $(".message-container input").focus();
},
validationErrorOk: function () {
    $("#validationErrorModal").detach();
    if (settings.focusedField) {
        settings.focusedField.focus();
    }
},
```

The field list is a list of objects that contain the id (field.id) of the DIV and also a description (field.fieldName) that I want to display.

Here is something I mocked up in paint...I am not sold on it but it show in a general sense what I am looking for:

[image]

I don't need a full solution rather, just want mechanisms I can use.

**UPDATE**

Just to help out anyone else in the future, using the info provided in the correct answer below I have a new code as follows:

```
<script id="template-validation-error" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div id="validationErrorModal" class="modal">
        <div class="validation-container">
            <div class="header" align="center">
                Validation Errors
            </div>
            <div class="message">
                <div class="scrolling-container" style="background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238); height:660px">
                    <div class="grid grid-pad">
                        {{#each fieldlist}}
                        <div class="row click-row" onclick="fffdevice.validationErrorFix('{{id}}');">
                            <div class="col-7-8 field-name">{{fieldName}}</div>
                            <div class="col-1-8">
                                <img class="pull-right" src="/mysite/Content/device/images/fix.png" style="width: 40px; position:relative; top: -5px;">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {{/each}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div><br/></div>
            <div class="center">
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-solid-green btn-sm" onclick="fffdevice.validationErrorOk();" value="Done" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Then the Javascript for the onClick is:

```
validationErrorFix: function (id) {
    $("#validationErrorModal").detach();
    var x = document.getElementById(id);
    x.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: "smooth", // or "auto" or "instant"
        block: "start" // or "end"
    });
},
```

Which closes the dialog and jumps to the field. It looks like (I know this is ugly and I will clean it up later):

[image]

Comment: Let me se if I understand, so there's some sort of form that the user needs to complete then when the user clicks submit or whatever if there are missing fields or errors a modal will pop with a list of actions to be taken to solve the validation process? once you close the modal that list will be transferred from the modal to the main div in the html?

Comment: @SergioAlen. Correct. The can validate the form, then it checks to see if fields have not been filled in, giving them a list. When they select one it should jump to that specific field for entry. At which point they can do validation again.

Comment: And the user can click on the list items where each one of them will take to the spedific input field?

Comment: @SergioAlen. Correct again. The idea is to close the modal and jump the user to the appropriate place to fill in the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the modal event to the validation code and show the modal if error(s) are found.

Display the modal with the list of errors using an html unordered list, inside the li element an anchor tag where the href attribute will have a value with the id that corresponds to the input field, all this done dynamically from your validation code.

Once an error in the list is clicked hide the modal using bootstrap    `$('#your-error-modal').modal('hide');` so the code would be something    like this:

```
$('#your-error-modal').on('click', 'a.error-item', function(){
    $('#your-error-modal').modal('hide');
});
```

I haven't tested this code, but if you're having issues with scrolling to the section of the input and closing the modal you can probably do something like this too:

```
$('#your-error-modal').on('click', 'a.error-item', function(e){ // use this method of onclick because your list will be created dynamically
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default anchor tag action
    var href = $(this).attr('href'); // grab the href value
    $('#your-error-modal').modal('hide'); // close the modal first
    scrollToDiv(href); // then take the user to the div with error with a nice smooth scroll animation
});

function scrollToDiv(location) {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(location).offset().top
    }, 2000);
}
```

Again this is untested code, but the idea is there.

For UX reasons you might also want to create a floating div or something where users can click on it and go back to the modal to continue reading your list of errors.

Comment: @sergioallen Awesome! I will give it a whirl and let know how it works...

Comment: Also good point about the floating div - I agree that something needs to be around if a lot of errors exist...thanks